# How does Admob determine the textual context to show targeted advertisements?

Tags: android, iphone, admob

1) Is the Admob SDK able to retrieve all the text strings shown in a app and display targeted ads based on those?

2) Do I have to specify the strings manually by `AdRequest.setKeywords(keywords)`? **EDIT**: `setKeywords` is ignored. [Source](http://groups.google.com/group/google-admob-ads-sdk/browse_thread/thread/26405e629c48a518)

3) The targeted ads are shown based on the application description and title entered in Admob website?

4) Some other factor(s)?

5) Non of parameters mentioned are used and **Admob does not provide context targeted ads** only region based ads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It not meaningful to parse the content as a web page on mobile devices, so the answer is no context targeted ads for now. I asked the same question with a googler. His answer is AdMob delivers Ads based on user's behavior. Initially, AdMob delivers any kinds of Ad to you. If you tap the "car" Ads more than the others, it means that you are interesting in buying a car recently, so more car Ads will be delivered to you, something like that.

Comment: do you happen to have any information about the app description in Admob web control panel? Is that taken into account when ads are served?

Comment: I don't specify any app desc information in Admob console. I don't think that Admob will take it into account; otherwise, it's easier for developer to spam the Ad system. As you know, we can put high price keyword in that desc information.

Answer (score 2):

From **my personal experience** it does not. I do not know but the ads I get are not particularly context sensitive.

I have a small free app called PodcastCharger and I set the keywords for the name of podcasts, etc but failed to see any difference with the ads shown.

**It could be that the keywords I set is not related to any ad.**

Answer (score 1):

I'll share my experience, I've just publish new app called Balloon Rush it's a simple tilt game so initially when I added ads it started displaying "Hot balloon" ads straight away which was odd as I have very few content as text in the app and that is mainly the title on the splash screen. After that I've added few keywords to the ad request and after an hour of the change I started getting different ads related to the keywords and even more image ads opposed  to text ones.

In my experience I saw good change adding keywords and it was definitely detecting my app title or in-app labels.