# How often is it ok to call loadAd(request)?

Tags: android, admob

I have an app in which the user navigates through content fairly quickly, then at some point they might stay with that content for a bit of time. I am adding part of that content as keywords to my ad request. So I would like to call `loadAd(request)` every time the user loads new content but that could be as fast as every 20 to 30 seconds, is that going to be an issue?

And just to be clear, I don't care whether the ad reloads every time I call `loadAd(request)`, my goal is just to feed enough keywords for it to be useful, maybe that is the wrong way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be surprized, but admob doesn't really care about the keywords.
So just load your ad, set maybe a refresh rate like 60s and that should be fine.
There will mostly show location-based ads depending on what google knows about the actual phone user. Very often you will see that the admob ad has actually nothing to do with app content itself.
Maybe that will change again over time, but as for now keywords seem to get pretty much ignored.

see also the related links here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9994435/2399024

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/JkBeYpxIpRg

Comment: Thanks for the info, but is it harmful for me to set the keyword anyways whenever the content the user sees changes? mostly asking because the code is already there.

Comment: Hard to say, but I remember the recommendation to not put a refresh interval lower then 60 sec. I assume the same applies for loadAd then